# Warning in Pluggable.php

Tags: plugins

I have installed wp on local laptop some functions are working while in appointment I get following warning on 'Submit'

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\esynapse\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:242) in C:\xampp\htdocs\esynapse\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1251

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\esynapse\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:242) in C:\xampp\htdocs\esynapse\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1254

Kindly guide me to resolve warning

Warm Regards

Giant

Comment: This is a common problem, and information is easily found via the googles/bings/ducks . The error lines tell you where the problem is occuring. Often, it is a result of a space character where it shouldn't be. Or a space character after a closing "?>" at the end of a php file (you don't need those).
A better question would be to tell us what you have done to try to figure out the problem, and to do a bit of research before you ask a question here. If you can't find the answer, tell us what you did to try to figure out the problem.

Comment: I have checked like no space before <?php nor blank line in.php which were edited in files mentioned in error also but these two files are not having ?>  at the end at the same time there is no space after last character

Comment: All plugins also I have deactivated and checked